# How to prevent the mistake of calling Object.values() on a Map

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

Recently I refactored some code and introduced a Map object where previously a plain object was used.

I am using Typescript so I've come to rely on the compiler shouting at me whenever I do something stupid, but in this case, my changes introduced some bugs because I was still calling `Object.values(mymap)`.

It's not a Typescript issue, because this is how the Node REPL behaves:

```
> const somemap = new Map([['a', 1],['b', 2]])
undefined
> Object.values(somemap)
[]
> somemap.values()
[Map Iterator] { 1, 2 }
>
```

Why am I allowed to call `Object.values()` on a `Map` if the result is an empty array instead of the actual values? And if the compiler can't help us, I would think that an ESLint rule can?

This fixes it `[...somemap.values()]`, but that's not the point. I would like to be protected against easy to make mistakes like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why am I allowed to call `Object.values()` on a `Map` if the result is an empty array instead of the actual values?

Because a map is still an object, it just doesn't have any own properties. You could in theory also create instances of a `Map` subclass that has some own properties, `Object.values` would then return them.

> And if the compiler can't help us, I would think that an ESLint rule can?

Yes, you should be able to build a typescript-eslint rule for this.

Comment: Created a `typescript-eslint` issue to track this: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/6807

Answer (score -2):

how about use custom prototype function?

```
const somemap = new Map([['a', 1],['b', 2]]);
Object.prototype.valuesOfMap = obj => {
    if (obj instanceof Map) return obj.values();
    return Object.values(obj);
}

const result = Object.valuesOfMap(somemap);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Seems like you didn't understand my question...